# Can't record voice in iOS 16 when the app is in background

Tags: avaudiosession

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
    
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"cclog = AVAudioSession SetCategory失败");
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"AVAudioSession SetCategory失败" code:-1 userInfo:nil];
        return;
    }
    
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
    
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"cclog = setActive失败");
        return;
    }
```

As the sample codes show above.I'm trying to launch a voice recorder while the app both in front and background.It runs perfectly in all iOS version when the app is in front.

But I get some error logs **just on iOS 16 with background mode** from the first line which printed as bellow:

**2022-10-12 18:14:08.848774+0800 Wearfit Pro[12288:2604335] [as_client]     AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:2370  Failed to set category, error: '!int'
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557684 "(null)"**

Any suggestion?